# POS tagging in Scala

Tags: scala, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I tried to POS tag a sentence in Scala using Stanford parser like below

```
val lp:LexicalizedParser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
lp.setOptionFlags("-maxLength", "50", "-retainTmpSubcategories")
val s = "I love to play"
val parse :Tree =  lp.apply(s)
val taggedWords = parse.taggedYield()
println(taggedWords)
```

I got an error **type mismatch; found : java.lang.String required: java.util.List[_ <: edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord]** in the line **val parse :Tree =  lp.apply(s)**

I don't know whether this is the right way of doing it or not. Are there any other easy ways of POS tagging a sentence in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a very simple way to do POS tagging in Scala

**Step 1**

Download stanford tagger version 3.2.0 form the link below

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-postagger-2013-06-20.zip

**Step 2**

Add **stanford-postagger** jar present in the folder to your project and also place the **english-left3words-distsim.tagger** file present in the models folder in your project

Then, with the code below you can pos tag a sentence in Scala

```
              val tagger = new MaxentTagger(
                "english-left3words-distsim.tagger")
              val art_con = "My name is Rahul"
              val tagged = tagger.tagString(art_con)
              println(tagged)
```

**Output:** My_PRP$ name_NN is_VBZ Rahul_NNP

Comment: There are scala bindings that make it even easier! takes a little work to install, but then that whole thing gets condensed to a single line.  The library is [here](https://github.com/gangeli/CoreNLP-Scala)

Answer (score 12):

You might like to consider the FACTORIE toolkit (http://github.com/factorie/factorie).  It is a general library for machine learning and graphical models that happens to include an extensive suite of natural language processing components (tokenization, token normalization, morphological analysis, sentence segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity recognition, dependency parsing, mention finding, coreference).

Furthermore it is written entirely in Scala, and it is released under the Apache License.

Documentation is currently sparse, but will be improving in the coming months.

For example, once Maven-based installation is finished you can type at the command line:

```
bin/fac nlp --pos1 --parser1 --ner1
```

to launch a socket-listening multi-threaded NLP server.  Then query it by piping plain text to its socket number:

```
echo "Mr. Jones took a job at Google in New York.  He and his Australian wife moved from New South Wales on 4/1/12." | nc localhost 3228
```

The output is then

```
1       1       Mr.             NNP     2       nn      O
2       2       Jones           NNP     3       nsubj   U-PER
3       3       took            VBD     0       root    O
4       4       a               DT      5       det     O
5       5       job             NN      3       dobj    O
6       6       at              IN      3       prep    O
7       7       Google          NNP     6       pobj    U-ORG
8       8       in              IN      7       prep    O
9       9       New             NNP     10      nn      B-LOC
10      10      York            NNP     8       pobj    L-LOC
11      11      .               .       3       punct   O

12      1       He              PRP     6       nsubj   O
13      2       and             CC      1       cc      O
14      3       his             PRP$    5       poss    O
15      4       Australian      JJ      5       amod    U-MISC
16      5       wife            NN      6       nsubj   O
17      6       moved           VBD     0       root    O
18      7       from            IN      6       prep    O
19      8       New             NNP     9       nn      B-LOC
20      9       South           NNP     10      nn      I-LOC
21      10      Wales           NNP     7       pobj    L-LOC
22      11      on              IN      6       prep    O
23      12      4/1/12          NNP     11      pobj    O
24      13      .               .       6       punct   O
```

Of course there is a programmatic API to all this functionality as well.

```
import cc.factorie._
import cc.factorie.app.nlp._
val doc = new Document("Education is the most powerful weapon which you can use to change the world.")
DocumentAnnotatorPipeline(pos.POS1).process(doc)
for (token <- doc.tokens)
  println("%-10s %-5s".format(token.string, token.posLabel.categoryValue))
```

will output:

```
Education  NN   
is         VBZ  
the        DT   
most       RBS  
powerful   JJ   
weapon     NN   
which      WDT  
you        PRP  
can        MD   
use        VB   
to         TO   
change     VB   
the        DT   
world      NN   
.          .
```

Comment: I just added factorie-1.0.0-M6.jar to the build path and it's showing the error "not found: value DocumentAnnotatorPipeline" on line DocumentAnnotatorPipeline.process(pos.POS1, doc). Do I need to add any more jars to make it work?

Comment: You need the cutting-edge version from GitHub.  We hope to make another milestone in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the API of the Stanford Parser has changed somewhat, as it does sometimes. `apply` has the signature, `public Tree apply(java.util.List<? extends HasWord> words)`, and this is what you see in the error message.

What you should use now is `parse`, which has the signature `public Tree parse(java.lang.String sentence)`.